# Google Chrome 101 on Android shows TAB key on soft keyboard instead of ENTER for HTML input field

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, enter, html-input, google-chrome-android

I am using Chrome 101 on Android 11. Setting the focus on a HTML input field brings up the soft keyboard. In earlier versions of Chrome, the soft keyboard then had the ENTER key on the lower right:
[Android Soft Keyboard ENTER key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiirh.png)

But now it shows the TAB key instead, for any input form field other than the last one in the form.
[Android Soft Keyboard TAB key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjJ8e.png)

Is there a way or setting, to change this to always show the ENTER key for input form fields?

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this using the [enterkeyhint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/enterkeyhint) attribute, for instance:

```
<input type="text" enterkeyhint="done"/>
```

"done" seems the best option, the others give strange behaviour...

Comment: I used <input type="search" enterkeyhint="search"/>

Comment: @togobites If your goal is to have a [SEARCH] button, then that's ok. Initially, our friend needed an [ENTER] button. In this case, it is better to use [DONE].

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
<input type="text"/>
```

by

```
<input type="search"/>
```